# Error in connecting (SSH) remote server (Mongo DB) through jump server using Paramico in python Script

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, ssh

I am trying to connect a Mongo DB server through jump server in my python script using Paramico on a AWS instance.

Let me explain how i connect to Mongo DB server on terminal on AWS:

```
    $ssh -i Key.pem harman@51.8.11.205 # I ssh on Jump server with this command
```

After login on to Jump server I use following command to SSH on Mongo DB server:

```
    $ssh ctpms-lmini1-Jsct1
```

here i do not require any authentication. No username, password or key is required.

Now i have to establish the same connection with python scrips. Here is my

Script:

```
    #Connect to Jump Server
    Jump_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    Jump_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    Jump_client.connect(hostname='51.8.11.205', port=22,
    username='harman', key_filename='key.pem', banner_timeout=10)
```

I am successfully able to connect to jump server and able to run :

```
    Jump_client.exec_command('ls')
```

Establish a channel between Mongo db server and Jump server:

```
    chan = client.get_transport()
    dest_addr = ('11.16.19.23', 22) #Mongo DB server IP#
    local_addr = ('51.8.11.205', 22) #Jump server IP#
    mongochannel = chan.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr,local_addr)
```

This was also succefull mongochannel is returning following:

```
    <paramiko.Channel 0 (open) window=2097152 in-buffer=23 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x7a952f90L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>
```

Now I am trying use mongochannel as socket  and creating new session but getting error:

```
    mongo_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    mongo_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    mongo_client.load_system_host_keys()
    mongo_client.connect(hostname='11.16.19.23', sock=mongochannel)
```

Here is the error:

```
    EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-26-2000cff93e10> in <module>()
   2 client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  3 client1.load_system_host_keys()
   ----> 4 client1.connect(hostname='11.16.19.23', sock=vmchannel)

   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.pyc in connect(self, hostname, port, username, password, pkey, key_filename, timeout, allow_agent, look_for_keys, compress, sock, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host, banner_timeout, auth_timeout, gss_trust_dns, passphrase)
395             sec_opts.key_types = [keytype] + other_types
396 
  --> 397         t.start_client(timeout=timeout)
398 
399         # If GSS-API Key Exchange is performed we are not required to check the

 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.pyc in start_client(self, event, timeout)
585                 e = self.get_exception()
586                 if e is not None:
  --> 587                     raise e
588                 raise SSHException("Negotiation failed.")
589             if event.is_set() or (

 EOFError:
```

As I mentioned earlier I do not require any username, password or key for mongodb. Please suggest.

I also tried jumpssh for this purpose but it also did not work.Here is the code:

```
   from jumpssh import SSHSession 
   gateway_session = SSHSession('51.8.11.205', 'test_user', proxy_transport=None, private_key_file='test.pem',
```

port=22, password=None, missing_host_key_policy=None,
compress=False)

Jump server connection worked fine but following code for mongodb server is giving error:

```
  remote_session = gateway_session.get_remote_session('11.16.19.23','test_user')
```

Error:

```
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-66-10b1b39a1f86> in <module>()
  ----> 1 remote_session = gateway_session.get_remote_session('11.16.19.23','harman')

  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jumpssh/session.pyc in get_remote_session(self, host, username, retry, private_key_file, port, password, retry_interval, compress)
496                                     password=password,
497                                     compress=compress).open(retry=retry,
 --> 498                                                             retry_interval=retry_interval)
499 
500         # keep reference to opened session, to be able to reuse it later

   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jumpssh/session.pyc in open(self, retry, retry_interval)
159                 else:
160                     raise exception.ConnectionError("Unable to connect to '%s:%s' with user '%s'"
  --> 161                                                     % (self.host, self.port, self.username), original_exception=ex)
162 
163         # Get the client's transport

  ConnectionError: Unable to connect to '11.16.19.23:22' with user 'test_user': [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Please note I also tried using same pem file for mongodb server that I use for jumpserver but it did not help.

Please provide your suggestions to resolve this.

Regards,
Bharat

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Are you trying to connect an SSH session to the "server with MongoDB installed"? Or are you trying to "Use an SSH Tunnel to talk to MongoDB for CRUD"? Those are two different things and your current approach is not how you do the latter one. If you want a "tunnel" then this is usually best set up as port forwarding separately to the application that wants to talk to MongoDB, With port forwarding your application just uses the "local port" which the other software layer forwards to the remote server.

Comment: Also please put auth credentials on your database. Even on a server with only SSH access it's really not safe to not have those.